# Chef recipe to unzip a file

Tags: chef-recipe

I'm looking for Chef recipe to unzip a file which I downloaded to a Windows 2012 EC2 instance. I'm using the below one. The Zip file (Try.Zip) is saved in C:\data directory and I wish to unzip it to the same folder.

zipfile 'C:\data\Try.zip' do
  into 'C:\data\'
end

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use `windows_zipfile` command to unzip the file and save in the `C:/foldername` location using the below Chef resource definition:

```
windows_zipfile 'C:/foldername' do
   source 'https://location/filename.zip'
   action :unzip
   overwrite true
end
```

You can find more information about this resource [in Chef documentation](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/windows#windows_zipfile)

Comment: I think this resource has been deprecated, I can't find it in v14

Answer (score 0):

Use the [seven_zip](https://github.com/windowschefcookbooks/seven_zip) cookbook. Example from readme fits your 'issue'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use batch as resource and used to extract file

```
batch 'extracting any zip' do
  code <<-EOH
  tar -xvf pathofzipfile
  EOH
  action :run
end
```

Comment: you can provide output path to tar command .By default it will extract in c drive